# Regular expression for prefix exclusion

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract *gmail.com* from a passage where I want only those string match that don't start with *@*.

Example: abc@gmail.com (don't match this); www.gmail.com (match this)

I tried the following: `(?!@)gmail\.com` but this did not work. This is matching both the cases highlighted in the example above. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ummm .. yes, that is what i meant :) prefix

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want a negative lookbehind if your regex supports it, like `(?<!@)gmail\.com` and add `\b`s to avoid matching `foogmail.comz`, like: `(?<!@)\bgmail\.com\b`

Answer (score 9):

```
[^@\s]*(?<!@)\bgmail\.com\b
```

assuming you want to find strings in a longer text body, not validate entire strings.

Explanation:

```
[^@\s]*     # match any number of non-@, non-space characters
(?<!@)      # assert that the previous character isn't an @
\b          # match a word boundary (so we don't match hogmail.com)
gmail\.com  # match gmail.com
\b          # match a word boundary
```

On a first glance, the `(?<!@)` lookbehind assertion appears unnecessary, but it isn't - otherwise the `gmail.com` part of `abc@gmail.com` would match.

Answer (score 2):

Use this regular expression using [negative lookbehind](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=regex%20lookbehind&fp=26b3281e04e74274&cad=b):

```
/^.*?(?<!@)gmail\.com$/
```